# Jetty crashes when requesting a page resulting in an exception. No more requests possible

Tags: java, exception, maven-3, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm currently on the way to setup a Java WebApp driven by Maven (Apache Maven 3.2.1) and the Jetty Maven plugin (jetty-maven-plugin:9.1.3).

The server starts fine with `mvn jetty:run`.

The current problem is that every time I request the login page, the following exception occurs in the console. Although it's only an INFO, it crashes the whole server. I can't do any request after that exception occurs.

The problem is that I can't find much about this failure on the net.

```
> Apr 16, 2014 2:35:18 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl
> throwIt INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the
> response. org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:298)
>         at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:453)
>         at com.sun.faces.application.ByteArrayWebOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayWebOutputStream.java:143)
>         at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.flushContentToWrappedResponse(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:149)
>         at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:381)
>         at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
>         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
>         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>         at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:711)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1644)
>         at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:171)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1615)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1624)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```